# How to train a Neural Network using Neuroph?

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm making a project for my Artificial Intelligence course which consists on predicting the bankruptcy of a company, based on some financial data.

For the project, which can be either in Java or C++, it was suggested that we used a framework, more specifically Neuroph.

Now, I've already written the part of the code which reads the data and puts it in a training set, but I'm not getting the results I hoped for.

For example, the data I'm reading has 64 data values and an output value which is either `0` (company has **not** entered bankruptcy) or `1` (**bankrupt company**). I have 6000 companies who do not enter bankruptcy and around 700 that do on my dataset.

When I input a company data, whether that company has entered bankruptcy or not, the value Neuroph gives me is **always near 1**. But I noticed this only happens when I insert the bankrupt companies data in the training set. Just one bankrupt company is enough to make the NN give me values higher than 0.9.

This is what I have when I create the network:

```
//create new network
ArrayList<Integer> layers = new ArrayList<>();
layers.add(64); // input data
layers.add(10); // intermediate neurons
layers.add(1);  // output data
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new MultiLayerPerceptron(layers);

//create training set
DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(64, 1);

//add training data of all years to training set

for(ArrfReader reader : readerArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.getFullDataSet().size(); i++) {
          trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(reader.getCompanyData(i), reader.getBankruptcyOfCompany(i)));
    }
}

//learn the training set
neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);
```

Now, I'm pretty sure I'm messing up on the new MultiLayerPerceptron constructor, but I don't know why. Any help or advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: 1. What is the minimum error value you are able to achieve?, why do you have that intermediate layer of neurons? and finally how are you normalizing your training data and test data ?